# spring or hibernate connection leak

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection

I am using spring with hibernate on a webapp (hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final and spring 3.2.11.RELEASE).
I am using hikaricp (v 2.2.5) as the connection pool impl which detects a connection leak and prints the stacktrace below. I am using spring's declarative transaction demarcation so I  assume the management and clean up of resources is done by spring/hibernate. Therefore, I think either spring or hibernate is the cause of the detected connection leak.

basically, there is timer which when fired, calls a spring bean marked with @Transactional annotation.

```
 @Transactional public class InvoiceCycleExporter {
public runExportInvoiceCycleJob(){
  //this method when called is **sometimes** leaking a connection ....
} }
```

can you please help me to trace the source of connection leak.

my appcontext.xml config for datasource, connection pool, entitymanager are below

```
 <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maximumPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="${jdbc.leakDetectionThreshold}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="velosPU"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>       //more stuff ....   
 </bean>
```

stacktrace below:

```
2015-01-13 14:25:00.123 [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0)] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.util.LeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: null
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70) ~[spring-orm-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61) ~[spring-orm-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-orm-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633) ~[spring-aop-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
        at com.ukfuels.velos.services.bl.internalinterface.impl.bl.invoicing.**InvoiceCycleExporter (this is the spring bean marked with the transactional annotation)**$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$519c078f.runExportInvoiceCycleJob(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:103) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.BacklogTracerInterceptor.process(BacklogTracerInterceptor.java:84) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:391) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:273) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:335) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:71) ~[camel-core-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint.onJobExecute(QuartzEndpoint.java:113) ~[camel-quartz-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:61) ~[camel-quartz-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223) ~[quartz-1.8.6.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549) ~[quartz-1.8.6.jar:na] **(a timer is triggered)**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is discussed here at large:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/34

To narrow the problem:

1. Try Spring 4 with Hibernate 4
2. Try another data-source to see if problem persists.

Comment: thanks for reply. I was using c3p0 datasource before hikari datasource and leak was also happening. So I am guessing either connection is being dropped prematurely by postgres (unlikely because tcp_keep_alive related settings in postgres.conf and linux os don't suggest so) or spring/hibernate is not releasing connection properly. I am using latest hibernate as of current 4.3.8.Final. I am not sure if I can upgrade to latest spring but will make further investigations

Comment: this could also be related to spring bug SPR-12280.

Comment: which of these things did you do, @abdel

Comment: hi @Stealth Rabbi, it has been a while but i remember it was a false alarm - i..e, not real leak. please see my answer below for general tips regarding this matter.

Answer (score 20):

here is some information that i think could be useful for debugging connection leaks in general

- Rule out false alarms. For example, if you have a transaction that could potentially run for 5 minutes (e.g., while producing a large report) 
  and you had set your 'leakDetectionThreshold' parameter (or whatever the equivalent for your chosen pool implementation) to 4 minutes, then any transaction taking longer than 4 minutes will be reported as a leak even though it may not be a genuine leak (transaction could complete gracefully and adequately release all connections after 5 minutes).
- If you are using a connection pool but find yourself running out of connections **occasionally** then think of how you configure your pool. In my case, I had configured the pool with 'maximumPoolSize'=100. Hikari will auto-default 'minimumIdle' config (minimum number of idle connections that HikariCP tries to maintain in the pool) to the same as that of 'maximumPoolSize' so on start-up the pool will be initialized with all max 100 connections. But this will mean that when the 'maxLifetime' (the maximum lifetime of a 
  connection in the pool) fires, then all connections will have to be renewed **at the same time**. This results in a **steep** temporary reduction of available connections. In my logs I was occasionally seeing following lines.

  HikariPool-0 (total=100, inUse=0, avail=100, waiting=0) 
  HikariPool-0 (total=4, inUse=0, avail=4, waiting=0) 
  HikariPool-0 (total=100, inUse=0, avail=100, waiting=0)

  the second line where available connections dropped to only 4, is when the 'maxLifetime' was reached and the connections needed renewal. So when configuring your pool, do it in a way so that the connections expire at different times. In my case, I simply changed 'minimumIdle' to 40, which means as load increases on server, new connections will be **incrementally** acquired (watch if your pool impl offers the equivalent of minToAcquire property) and hence those connections will have different expiry dates.
- Your connection 'maxLifetime' need to be less than what your database assigns/expects for connections so that you don't end up with connections in the pool that are invalid. **UPDATE:** some databases may force drop the connection after a period of time. For example, postgres has a 'connectionTimeout' and 'socketTimeout' options. So in your application's connection pool, you don't want to keep connections for longer than this db-enforced-connection-timeout because otherwise you will be keeping an invalid/already-dropped connection.

Comment: can you elaborate on "database assigns/expects for connections"?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Basically some databases may force drop the connection after sometime. For example, postgres has a 'connectionTimeout' and 'socketTimeout' options. So in your application's connection pool, you don't want to keep connections for longer than this db-enforced-connection-timeout because otherwise you will be keeping an invalid/already-dropped connection