# DB Connections in SpringBoot using HikariCP

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

While I was performing a load test on the Restful service developed through Springboot and deployed as a microservice in Kubernetes cluster, I encountered an issue with DB connection pool size. On reading about the connection pooling, I have added Hikari configuration settings in "application.properties" file and tested again. The test was better and but still sometimes it fails with DB connection error like Connections are not available and connection timeout. I stop the load test and try to validate the service by invoking it separately, even then I see DB connection not available error. I end up resetting the Pod's to come out of this issue, is there a time when it Pod comes back to normal or is it needed the JVM to be restarted (in my case, it is Pod)? Please suggest

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:....
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

#connection pool configuration
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=SVConnectionPool
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=60
```

Error seen in the logs

```
2023-07-19T05:59:46.455208060Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2023-07-19T05:59:46.455436540Z Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: SVConnectionPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 76386ms.
2023-07-19T05:59:46.455448334Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)
2023-07-19T05:59:46.455481188Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)
2023-07-19T05:59:46.456083667Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
2023-07-19T05:59:46.456094566Z  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117)
2023-07-19T05:59:46.456286268Z  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    ... 88 more
2023-07-19T05:59:46.456769448Z org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: SVConnectionPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 76386ms.
```

Comment: Please show your code / k8s resources / stacktrace as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting suggests a database connection leak or some very slow DB operations which cause all connections from the pool to hang.

To fix the problem, you first have to identify the source code which causes hanging connections and fix it.

Here are some tips:

- Check for hanging connections in the database, after you find them, identify the source code and inspect it
- Use property `spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold = 10000` to automatically detect and log leaks
- Use property `logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari = DEBUG` to see additional logs from Hikari
- Use property `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` to reduce lifetime of the connections
- Checkout Vlad Mihalcea's article: [the-best-way-to-detect-database-connection-leaks](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-detect-database-connection-leaks/)
- Checkout related Stack Overflow questions such as [spring or hibernate connection leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925914/spring-or-hibernate-connection-leak)